# Adding auto-incremenation on a VARCHAR column on an SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, alter-table

I need to alter `customer_number` column in `organisation` table so, that it would become auto-incrementable.

As in, when adding rows to the table, this certain column would get bigger number each time. It is not the id column.

**Example:** If there would be no rows or only rows that have no value on `customer_number` column, the newly added `organisation` row would get 1 as the value for its `customer_number` column. If there would be already for example two rows with values on said column - say 100 and 200 - the new row would get value 201 on that column.

Is that even possible to do by altering an existing table and column?

Comment: Sounds like you should have an integer column that increments, and then construct this customer number string using it (computed column or a view).

Comment: See the documentation on [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for the restrictions and what is possible.